# Des montagnes russes?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Pourquoi appelle-toi ces attractions de fêtes foraines des "montagnes russes"? L'analogie à des montagnes est sans doute évidente, mais pourquoi celles de Russie? Qu'est-ce qui est historiquement à l'origine de ce choix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selon [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montagnes_russes#Histoire) :

> Le concept de « montagnes russes » vient des courses de luges se déroulant sur des collines de neige spécialement construites pour celles-ci, particulièrement dans les environs de Saint-Pétersbourg.

Comment: Pour l'amusement, en russe cela se traduit par   
американские горки , c'est-à-dire montagnes américaines ...